# Android Emulator on RDP

Tags: android, opengl, android-emulator, rdp

I have access to a Virtual Machine in my office's network through RDP. I am trying to setup my Android Project on that, but unfortunately the android emulator does not start on that VM. It shuts down with the following error in the Android Studio console:

> Could not initialize emulator framebuffer ERROR: Could not create renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver

I searched the internet and found that it has something to do with OpenGL. RDP does not support OpenGL 2.0 which is required by the emulator.
I also tried to use Genymotion but it also failed with the error related to OpenGL.

So is there any work around or any other solution/alternative to start the emulator on a RDP?

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue using android studio in a virtual win7 machine.
I used this bundle adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip instead of android emulator, added 4.4.2 sdk platform and system images and worked properly.

Comment: I tried it. But it's giving the same error in eclipse too.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on Virtual environment and find out that issue (in our case) was related to SDK version. 24.1.2 SDK causes problem on virtual machines.
We've downgrade to version [24.0.2](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.0.2-windows.exe) and issue was solved